# gigabit router slows down on long range ethernet cable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, ethernet

I have set up a basic FTTH in my home I have:

- 150 Mbps Connection
- Mi Router 4A Gigabit
- TP-Link Gigabit Switch (5 Ports)
- Tenda Cat6 Cable

My Router sits 131 Feet away from my laptop if I connect with or without a switch to my laptop with a patch cable like 1 foot I get the full bandwidth of around 150 Mbps but when I connect to my patch which is 131 feet away I get 100 Mbps, I tried crimping cat 6 connectors but no fun, so I want to ask do I need to buy a new router which supports it? I'm not sure which router will help in that case. Secondly, I followed the T-568B method to clip the connectors.

At this point it's clear to me that either ethernet does not support this kind of long-range for a gigabit port rather it slows down to 100 Mbps or my router does not support or does not have the energy to travel the signal at that speed.

Please guide.

Thanks

Comment: CAT6 should absolutely support a 40 meter run.  There is something else going on which you have not identified.

Comment: Did you use CAT6 connectors too?

Comment: "*clip the connectors*" -- That would be crimp not "*clip*".  "*when I connect to my patch ..*" -- What exactly is this "*patch*"? UTP and STP cable must not be treated like rope. Avoid twisting, kinking, or pulling on the cable.  An abused/damaged cable can/will have degraded performance as you report. Have you abused your cable at all?

Comment: one note op, traditionally, `b` means bit. and `B` means byte. Gigabit (1000mbps) generally tops out at a 125 MegaBytes/s, whereas 100mbps can reach about 12 MegaBytes/s. So which of your measurements are megabits and which are megaBytes?

Comment: @Ramhound yes that's what I'm looking into.

Comment: @LPChip yes i did use the Cat 6 connector pins and crimped them can see it in zigzag pattern

Comment: @sawdust its not twisted at all just a bit of bending along the path 131 feet but it won't affect the speeds since i have fiber and another cat6 and its alright, the cable is all good

Comment: @FrankThomas Internet bandwidth is 150 Mbps == 12.5 MBps, routers and ports are supported upto 1024 Mbps == 1 Gigabit

Comment: Even Cat5e should be capable of 1Gbps for *at least* ~100m; "not having the energy required" would be somewhat of a spec violation. Are you testing both the cable _and_ the switch at the same time, or are you skipping the switch and connecting your laptop directly to the cable? (Please test both ways.) Also, do all the involved devices show 1Gbps or 100Mbps as the _negotiated_ link rate? (Not as in speed test, but as in ethernet interface status.) If they show 1Gbps negotiated but can't reach above 100Mbps that's one kind of problem; if they show 100Mbps negotiated that's another problem.

Comment: @user1686 the 131 feet cat 6 cable shows 100/100 negotiation, but the 1-2 feet patch cable shows 1 gig negotiation and i get 150 Mbps full speeds

Comment: Instead of submitting several comments, you should [edit] your question, comments are temporary and can be removed at any time.

Comment: What model is the switch, does it have a built-in cable test feature? (Have you used any cable test device on this cable?)

Answer (score 0):

Twisted-pair Ethernet generally supports up to 100 m. According to standard, 90m need to be stiff, solid-core cabling, and up to 10m flexible, stranded patch cable. Using decent cabling, you can normally get away with 30-50m patch cable as well.

If your installation only works for short distances and links down to 100 Mbit/s or fail to link altogether, check:

1. discontinuity: 1000BASE-T requires all four pairs to work
2. mismatched pairs: cables need to be kept in their original pairing; swapping conductors between pairs severely increases crosstalk - if you can't make out the original pairs remove more of the outer sleeve
3. mismatched connectors or tooling: make sure the connectors you crimp are suitable for the cable type and gauge
4. do not overdo or underdo the twisting rate: try to preserve the original twisting rate and *direction* of the cabling - failure to do so increases attenuation and decreases reach
5. if there's a shield, it needs to be properly grounded on *both* sides - alternatively, consider UTP